# Select a txt file from list then read all data selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to `fcaption` will select one file randomly from that list then read all text.
anybody can help or give references?

```
fcaption = open('caption-1.txt','caption-2.txt','caption-3.txt','caption-4.txt',.....) 
f1 = fcaption.read()
pyperclip.copy(f1)

caption = pyperclip.paste()
time.sleep(random.randrange(5,6))

type_caption = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('textarea._ablz._aaeg')
type_caption.send_keys(caption)
```

Answer (score 0):

`random.choice()` would fit your needs nicely. Other than that, I don't see a compelling reason to use `pyperclip`, since `.read()` will store your data as a variable, and you wouldn't need the clipboard, just call `send_keys(caption)` like you already have:

```
import random
import time


fcaption = ('caption-1.txt','caption-2.txt','caption-3.txt','caption-4.txt') 

f1 = random.choice(fcaption)

with open(f1, 'r') as file:    # using 'with' is much safer for opening files
    caption = file.read()      #    since it closes automatically after .read()

time.sleep(random.randrange(5,6))

type_caption = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('textarea._ablz._aaeg')
type_caption.send_keys(caption)
```